# Numerical evaluation of infinite sums

Tags: convergence, cumulative-distribution-function, computational-statistics, sum, skellam-distribution

I am working with Skellam random variables and I would like to evaluate the CDF of the absolute value of a Skellam random variable in which both Poisson random variables have the same rate, $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda$. I.e.

$$
\begin{align}
P(|W|=\nu) &= 2e^{-2\lambda}I_\nu(2\lambda) \ \ \ \nu >0 \\
     &= e^{-2\lambda}I_0(2\lambda) \ \ \ \ \ \nu = 0
\end{align}
$$

Where $I_\nu(2\lambda)$ is the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1).

Prakash Balachandra et al showed that

$$P(|W|>\nu) = 2e^{-2\lambda} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{I_{\nu+i}(2\lambda)}$$

or alternatively

$$\log P(|W|>\nu) = \log 2 -2\lambda + \log \left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{I_{\nu+i}(2\lambda)} \right)$$

I would like to write code to evaluate this expression quickly and accurately.  I have limited experience with numerical summation of infinite series.  My only idea is to iteratively sum to N and stop when $\log \left( \sum_{i=1}^{N}{I_{\nu+i}(2\lambda)} \right)$ meets some convergence criteria, though I am not certain how precise it ought to be.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The canonical way would be to estimate the tail $\sum_{i=R+1}^\infty I_{\nu+i}(2\lambda)$, determine for which $R$ this tail is small enough, then use the partial sum up to $R$. Unfortunately, $I_\nu$ is not an easy beast to tackle. If you trust anonymous internet sources, the first recurrence formula on p. 20 [here](http://mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap4.pdf) may be useful: $I_{\nu+1}(x) = I_{\nu-1}(x)-\frac{2\nu}{x}I_\nu(x)$.